# Generate all possibilities in scheme from a list

Tags: list, scheme

I have a list of sublists:

```
((a b c) (e f) (z h))
```

and i want to generate something like this:

```
((a e z) (a f z) (a e h) (a f h) (b e z) (b e h) ... ) and so on.
```

I want, given a list of sublist, to generate all possibilities of sublists that contains an element from each of the input's sublists.

How can i get this ouput?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're describing the [cartesian product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product) of a list of lists, here's a possible implementation (works in Racket):

```
(define (cartesian-product lsts)
  (foldr (lambda (lst acc)
           (for*/list ((x (in-list lst))
                       (y (in-list acc)))
             (cons x y)))
         '(())
         lsts))
```

Now, if you're not using Racket, here's a vanilla implementation using mostly standard procedures; it should work on any Scheme interpreter that defines a `fold-right`-like procedure:

```
(define (flatmap f lst)
  (apply append (map f lst)))

(define (cartesian-product lsts)
  (foldr (lambda (lst acc)
           (flatmap (lambda (x)
                      (map (lambda (y)
                             (cons x y))
                           acc))
                    lst))
         '(())
         lsts))
```

Either way, it works as expected:

```
(cartesian-product '((a b c) (e f) (z h)))

=> '((a e z) (a e h) (a f z) (a f h) (b e z) (b e h)
     (b f z) (b f h) (c e z) (c e h) (c f z) (c f h))
```

Comment: for*/list: undefined;
 cannot reference undefined identifier

Should i import something?

Comment: ... so, you're not using Racket :( . I can translate the above code to a more neutral dialect of Scheme, but it'll take me a while.